# htaccess rewrite showing redundant root folder

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I've searched but haven't found a solution to this exact problem.

I have a website domain 'mainwebsite.com' and several other top-level-domains managed in the htaccess. The issue I'm having is with 'alternatedomain.com' and subdirectories.

```
#alternatedomains

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} alternatedomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/alternatedomain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ alternatedomain/$1 [L]
```

This works fine,  alternatedomain.com happily serves up mainwebsite.com/alternatedomain .

The problem is when I have access any folder like

```
alternatedomain.com/folder
```

, the URL in the title bar changes to

```
alternatedomain.com/alternatedomain/folder/
```

and it's driving me crazy. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

EDIT: It only happens when I try access alternate.com/folder, and not when there is a suffix /, so alternate.com/folder/ works fine, without the redundant folder name

Your help is most appreciated!

Comment: There's several things that could be causing this. Check out one of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rewrite+trailing+slash

Answer (score 0):

This is because mod_dir (that adds the `/`) does not know the url is rewritten.

You could just disable DirectorySlash with

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

This will however make requests to `alternatedomain.com/folder` result in a 404 not found. You can fix this with some rewriterule though. So the complete solution would be something like:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 -d
RewriteRule ^alternatedomain/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R,L]
```